# Calling/mapping another entity in getter with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider this simple database schema:

```
 User                Relation            Property
+-------------+     +--------------+     +---------------+
| -user_id    |     | -relation_id |     | -property_id  |
|             |     | -source_id   |     |               |
|             |     | -target_id   |     |               |
|             |     | -type        |     |               |
+-------------+     +--------------+     +---------------+
```

The `relation` table contains multiple source and target ids (as STRING) from another tables and "connect" dynamically difficult types of entities. So the `source_id` can be a `user_id` and `target_id` `property_id`, but also other entities and vice versa.

Now I want in `User` the `properties` over the `relation` table when type is `property`.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "source", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Where(clause = "type = 'PROPERTY'")
  @ElementCollection
  private Set<Relation> properties;
```

This works perfectly fine. I receive the `relation` entity with the property id as string in `target_id`.

Is it possible to resolve this and extend the getter, so that i receive the real property entity?
Like calling the propertyRepository within the user entity. As a newbie in java and jpa/hibernate im a bit lost here.